# K8s job memory consumption after job finishes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

On below dashboard, yellow line represents memory limit, red line represents memory requests and green memory usage. Why is memory consumption still being reported by Prometheus after job completion? I checked job logs and job completed same time when memory request and limits went to 0. Job TTL is set to 60 sec so I think it's not related.

[prometheus grafana metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DSuaZ.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factually a completed job means the process is no longer running let a lone consuming any resources. So, what you see in your logs is probably due to a delay in the metrics refresh period.

Keep in mind that K8s-related metrics like resource requests are reported by reaping information from the K8s API-Server, whereas actual resource consumption is reported by different infrastructure components, e.g. the Metrics Server. Those systems will likely have different refresh periods, which explains the discrepancy when you aggregate them on the same chart.